# Why isn't path showing on map in activity posted to Google Fit using REST API?

Tags: rest, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am using Google Fit REST API (via Google Java Client Library) to post an activity into Google Fit.

In summary what I am doing is creating three `DataSet`s covering the given time period:

- `"com.google.location.sample"` - Location
- `"com.google.step_count.delta"` - Steps
- `"com.google.calories.expended"` - Calories

... then creating a `Session`, and finaly a `DataSet` with a single Activity Segment (in this case all the time is walking).

This basically all seems to work - I can looking in http://fit.google.com, and I can see the activity, with the correct time, location, duration, steps and calories. The problem is with the map... all it shows is a shaded circle over the whole area of the walking - it doesn't show the track/path that I included in the location `DataSet`.

EDIT... Here is [an example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B30sfAX3IWcGRmdSLTNaNmZYMU0/view?usp=sharing) of what it looks like (in web UI).

Why would this not be showing up correctly, when all of the rest of the activity shows up perfectly?

These are some of my suspicions

- My data does not have either `altitude` or `accuracy` - which are two of the fields needed by `"com.google.location.sample"`. So I set `altitude` to 0.0 (metres), and set `accuracy` to 5.0 (metres). I particularly wonder if Google is reacting badly to me setting the altitude to 0.0 for each point?
- My location DataSet has say 100 `DataPoint`s in it, whereas by steps and calories `DataSet`s only have one `DataPoint` in each - i.e. I only have total steps, and total calories, for the walk. So there's an inconsistency (the earliest start and latest end dates are the same for each data set)

Can anybody give any guidance about why this is happening please?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet or screenshot of what you are getting?

Comment: @SwagBomb - Edited to add link to example image. Thanks

Comment: Interested to know if that has helped.  I see the same thing but I have never seen the website give anything but the circle you are seeing.  I guess I should use the fit app for an explicit activity now that is possible and see what turns up.

Comment: I did a test this morning explicitly recording my commute with the fit app.  In the fit app I have the exact map with the route but on the website I just have the normal big circle.  My conclusion is that the website just has no support for plotting the detailed route.

Answer (score 0):

Think this may be due to conflicting data points. As stated [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history#manageConflicting). Although this is for the API for Android, I think it holds true too when using the REST API.

> Each `DataPoint` in your app's `DataSet` must have a `startTime` and an
>   `endTime` that defines a unique interval within that `DataSet`, with no
>   overlap between `DataPoint` instances. If your app attepts to insert a
>   new `DataPoint` that conflicts with an existing `DataPoint` instance, the
>   new `DataPoint` is discarded. To insert a new `DataPoint` that may overlap
>   existing data points, use the `HistoryApi.updateData` method described in
>   Update data.

You mentioned that the dates are the same across data points. Thus overriding the others and it is only treated as one.

For your `com.google.location.sample` data type fields. Think it's better to leave them as is. Try not to place a static value and for `altitude` and `accuracy`.